# No value given for one or more required parameters with OleDBDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, dataadapter, oledbdataadapter

Hey all I realise that this question has been asked before but even if I follow the answers I still cannot seem to get my code to work. The error occurs at "data_adapter.Fill(temp_table)" any help on what is going on would be appreciated.

```
string ConnStr = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = H:\\School Work\\Computing A Level\\Stock checker\\Program\\Morgan's Motors Database.mdb";

string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Car Info] WHERE @x ";
string FirstQuery = null;

int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < ColumnName.Count - 1; i++)
{
    FirstQuery += string.Format("{0} = {1} AND ", ColumnName[i], EnteredFields[i]);
}

FirstQuery += string.Format("{0} = {1}", ColumnName[i], EnteredFields[i]);

MessageBox.Show(Query);

OleDbConnection database_connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);

OleDbCommand database_command = new OleDbCommand(Query, database_connection);
database_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", FirstQuery);

OleDbDataAdapter database_adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
database_adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(database_command.CommandText, database_connection);

DataTable temp_table = new DataTable();

database_adapter.Fill(temp_table);

BindingSource data_source = new BindingSource();

data_source.DataSource = temp_table;

dataGridView1.DataSource = data_source;
```

EDIT: I have made some progress in restructuring the code, now the problem is that the "?" isn't being replaced

string ConnStr = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = H:\School Work\Computing A Level\Stock checker\Program\Morgan's Motors Database.mdb;";

```
            OleDbConnection conn_database = new OleDbConnection();
            conn_database.ConnectionString = ConnStr;

            OleDbCommand comm_database = new OleDbCommand();
            comm_database.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Car Info] WHERE ? = ?";
            comm_database.Connection = conn_database;

            OleDbDataAdapter adap_database = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm_database);

            DataTable data_database = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnName.Count; i++)
            {
                comm_database.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ColumnName[i].ToString());
                comm_database.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", EnteredFields[i].ToString());

                MessageBox.Show(adap_database.SelectCommand.CommandText);

                adap_database.Fill(data_database);
            }

            BindingSource bind_database = new BindingSource();
            bind_database.DataSource = data_database;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bind_database;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using string manipulation to create queries - it leaves you subject to SQL Injection Attacks. Use parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
database_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", EnteredFields[i]);
```

instead of :

```
database_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", FirstQuery);
```

Usually when working with parameter you can just add the param name and its value and not have to add the columnName = to the value.  Make sense?

One thing that you could try if wanted to leverage using parameters is code below.  I don't know if it will solve your problem or not but at least it help protect you from SQL Injection attacks.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM [Car Info] WHERE {0} ";

for (i = 0; i < ColumnName.Count - 1; i++)
{
    FirstQuery += string.Format("{0} = @{1} AND ", ColumnName[i], ColumnName[i]);
}
FirstQuery += string.Format("{0} = @{1}", ColumnName[i], ColumnName[i]);
Query = String.Format(Query, FirstQuery);

for (i = 0; i < ColumnName.Count - 1; i++)
{
    database_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ColumnName[i], EnteredFields[i]);
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I think I needed to be a bit more clearer in my first post. The query entered depends on the amount of parameters entered by the user for example the user in one query may only look for CarID but in another they make look for CarID, Manufacturer and Model meaning I need the query options in the same variable unless if I do a for loop to add them one at a time which I'm not sure will work.

But thanks for the help!

Comment: My next guess would be that one of the EnteredFields values is blank.  So you FirstQuery string might look like: CarId = AND MakeId = 1234.

Comment: Okay, I'll stick a MessageBox in somewhere now to test that idea

Comment: No they are all there when entering the info. Could it be something to do with the types of data being entered into the query? CarID is an integer while other items such as Manufacturer and Model are text.

I have thought of this before but I'm not sure how to correct it

Comment: I believe that Access throws the error mentioned above when there is a data type conversion errors. For integers and boolean in SQL type statements do not need to be surrounded by quotes. ex: CarId =1234 is valid.  String type fields and guids do.  ex:  Make = 'value'.  Usually you can rely on the parameter collection to format this for you, but the way that you your where clause I a guessing that this is not happening.

Comment: I was aware of the naming conventions for strings by adding the ' around them which I do when collecting them from the text boxes. I still think it is a data type conversion error but I can't seem to figure out where

Comment: Ok.  Cool. My next guess and I am sure you already thought of this is that there is a string in a number type field.  ex: assuming CarId is a numeric field. CarId = my nice car.

Comment: Like you said I've already thought of this and as far as I can tell I haven't got any strings in my number fields. To collect all the data I'm using a List<object> as there are strings and ints which need to be taken, could this be the problem? Also thanks for going through this with me!

Comment: One thing that you could try if wanted to leverage using parameters is code below.  I don't know if it will solve your problem or not but at least it help protect you from SQL Injection attacks.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, what do you mean by "code below"? The database would only be used on a LAN not connected to the internet so SQL injection would be a hard to perform attack

Comment: ok.  cool. np.  you are welcome.   Sorry, my code would not fit in the comments, so I added it to my answer above.

Comment: ok. two last suggestions.  1).  you might want to do .toStrings() on known string fields and int.parse() on known int fields. I don't know if that will help or not and it might be a pain so maybe try #2 first. 2).  limit number of parameter you add until you find the problem ex:  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++).  If that doesn't blow up then try for (i = 0; i < 2; i++), etc until you find the offending parameter.  then you might have a better idea which param is causing trouble and how to fix it

Comment: The @ still seem to be present rather than being replaced by the .AddWithValue code